# Trigger an action to start after X milliseconds

Tags: c#, mvvm, task-parallel-library, portable-class-library, xamarin.forms

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms mobile app, which has a page containing a SearchBar, a ListView, and Map control.  The list view contains a list of addresses, which are reflected as pins on the map.

As the user types in the SearchBar, the ListView is automatically updated (through ViewModel binding).  The ViewModel method that filters the datasource for the list looks something like this...

```
void FilterList()
{
    listDataSource = new ObservableCollection<location>(
        locationData.Where(l => l.Address.Contains(searchBar.Text))
    );

    // ***** Now, update the map pins using the data in listDataSource
}
```

I want to update the Map as the ListView is filtered, but not on EVERY keypress as that could happen multiple times a second.  Essentially, I want a "rolling pause" in each FilterList event before the Map is updated.  In pseudo-code...

```
    // ***** Now, update the map pins using the data in listDataSource
    if (a previously-requested map update is pending)
    {
        // Cancel the pending map update request
    }

    // Request a new map update in 1000ms using [listDataSource]
```

It's possible to do this using the **Stopwatch** class, which is available in Portable Class Libraries, but I suspect there's a cleaner/better way to accomplish this using **Tasks**.

Can anyone suggest a "cleverer" **PCL-compatible** way to do this?

Comment: What PCL profile are you using?

Comment: Profile7 - portable-net45+netcore45+MonoAndroid1+MonoTouch1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with simple delays is that you can get a bunch of events queued up for when the delay expires. You can add logic to throw away the events that were raised while the delay was running. If you want to declare the logic at a higher level, you can use [Reactive Extensions](http://reactivex.io/).

Comment: Thanks @edward-brey - I bound the Text property of a Field to a ViewModel property, and used that to fire a TextChanged event, and then used Rx Observable.FromEventPattern with the event, using .Throttle(TimeSpan) to define the interval at which the events would actually bubble up.

Answer (score 24):

you can try :

```
await Task.Delay(2000);
```

Comment: Task.Delay is available in PCL (and in Profile7), and there are overloads that take a CancellationToken.

Comment: I m using in Xamarin.Forms to delay my animations, so i can assure it works.

Comment: My bad guys - I was basing my comments on the [MSDN documentation for Task.Delay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194865(v=vs.110).aspx) and the fact that PCL isn't included in the Version Information section (in the way that PCL **is** included in the Version Information section for the Task class as a whole).

Comment: This answer is only part of what is needed to solve what is in the question. How "cancel the pending update"? So that several quick key presses don't trigger several updates. [HarshitGindra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44479759/199364) is more complete.

Answer (score 13):

Just like you said this can be accomplished in a very clean way using `Tasks` and async programming.

You will want to read about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Here's an example:

```
public async Task DelayActionAsync(int delay, Action action) 
{
    await Task.Delay(delay);

    action();
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned to Rui, the Delay method on the Task class is not available in PCL, so that's not an option for me.

Comment: @bosco It looks to me like it is available in Profile7 (in VS 2013).

Comment: My bad @svick - I was basing my comments on the [MSDN documentation for Task.Delay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194865(v=vs.110).aspx) and the fact that PCL isn't included in the Version Information section (in the way that PCL **is** included in the Version Information section for the Task class as a whole).

Comment: @bosco Well, a PCL profile should be just an intersection of some set of framework versions. So, if something is available in all the versions that are relevant to you, it should be available in PCL too. I *think* what PCL mentioned in the docs is supposed to mean is that it's available in all PCL profiles.

Answer (score 13):

Here is what I've done and it works in my Xamarin Form apps.

```
    public string Search
    {
        get { return _search; }
        set
        {
            if (_search == value)
                return;

            _search = value;
            triggerSearch = false;
            Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                string searchText = _search;
                await Task.Delay(2000);
                if (_search == searchText)
                {
                    await ActionToFilter();
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I've this 'Search' Property binded to my Entry field. Whenever the user filters something, code waits for 1 second and then compares the new Text field with the field it was before 1 second before. Assuming the string is equal implies that user has stopped entering the text and code can now be triggered to filter.

Comment: What is `triggerSearch`?

Comment: triggerSearch is the property I use to inform the UI whether filtering has started. Its the way I use to make the user aware if any backend processing is going on. Although it is not required for this question. I forgot to take it out.

Answer (score 0):

### Working in latest xamarin version.

Another Great method way on button click is ,

```
    public async void OnButtonClickHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //ShowProgresBar("Loading...");

        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Task.Delay(2000); //wait for two seconds

            //TODO Your Business logic goes here
            //HideProgressBar();

        });

        await DisplayAlert("Title", "Delayed for two seconds", "Okay");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

`async` and `await` keys are important, suppose if you working on multithread environment.

Comment: `Task.Delay(2000)` is 2 seconds, not 2 milliseconds.

Comment: This seems overly complicated. You are already in an `async` method. Why put `Task.Delay` inside `Task.Run`? Why not do what already existing answers do, which is simply `await Task.Delay`? I don't see what this answer contributes to this Q&A. (Its also worth reviewing https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html)

Comment: sorry, ignore the link I just gave. That isn't the problem here. There is nothing inherently wrong with the way you coded; it just felt a bit cleaner to move Task.Delay out of the Task.Run - though I see that does requiring prefixing that line also with `await`, so on further thought, what you did is justifiable.