# How to run code after a delay in Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-runonuithread

I'm trying to show some code after a delay in my Android app.
The Java code for doing this is something like this:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
   @Override
   public void run()
   {
     // your code that you want to delay here
   }
}, 1000/* 1000ms = 1sec delay */);
```

How do I do this in Xamarin.Android with C#?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can try this:

```
Handler h = new Handler();
Action myAction = () => 
{
    // your code that you want to delay here
};

h.PostDelayed(myAction, 1000);
```

Take a look at [document](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.OS.Handler.PostDelayed/p/Java.Lang.IRunnable/System.Int64/)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can implement this in this instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124434/animate-recyclerview-items-one-by-one ?

Comment: Do you know a Xamarin.Forms equivalent ?

Comment: @MaximeEsprit you can use C# `Task.Delay` https://stackoverflow.com/a/25188225/719212

Comment: Chears @R4j Thank you for your answer

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to use cross-platform timer like [AdvancedTimer](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Mobilist.AdvancedTimer.Forms.Plugin/). Check:[github repo](https://github.com/ufuf/AdvancedTimer)

**API Usage**

To gain access to the Timer class simply use the dependency service:

```
IAdvancedTimer timer = DependencyService.Get<IAdvancedTimer>();
```

You MUST call initTimer for timer initialization;

```
timer.initTimer(3000, timerElapsed, true);

initTimer(interval, Eventhandler function, AutoReset);
```

**Methods**

```
timer.startTimer();

timer.stopTimer();

timer.getInterval()

timer.setInterval(5000);

timer.isTimerEnabled();
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can implement this in this instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39124434/animate-recyclerview-items-one-by-one ?